# Julia popfirst! is throwing error for PriorityQueue

Tags: julia, priority-queue

```
using DataStructures
x = PriorityQueue(Base.Order.Forward, "a" => 2, "b" => 3, "c" => 1)
Base.popfirst!(x)
```

is throwing error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching popfirst!(::PriorityQueue{String, Int64, Base.Order.ForwardOrdering})
Closest candidates are:
  popfirst!(::OrderedSet) at C:\Users\Vinod\.julia\packages\OrderedCollections\SInLM\src\ordered_set.jl:58
  popfirst!(::AbstractChannel) at channels.jl:11
  popfirst!(::CircularDeque) at C:\Users\Vinod\.julia\packages\DataStructures\MKv4P\src\circ_deque.jl:91
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[34]:1
```

all other methods seems to be working.

[DataStructures](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/priority-queue/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the documentation for the in-development version (you can see that on the bottom left in the sidebar, it says "Version [dev]"). So `popfirst!` will be available in the next version of DataStructures (unless that decision changes for some reason - since it's still an in-development version).

To access the documentation for the current version, you can click on that `[dev]` box on the bottom left and choose `stable` instead (or if you're using an older version of DataStructures for some reason, choose that instead). For the current stable version, you can use `dequeue_pair!` or `dequeue!` instead of `popfirst!`:

> ```
> dequeue!(pq)              # remove and return the lowest priority key
> dequeue_pair!(pq)         # remove and return the lowest priorty key and value
> ```

from https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/priority-queue/#Priority-Queue-1